# username field in django sign up form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-users

I use `from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm`
 in forms.py for creating sign up form.
first I register with a username, for example `ali` and again when I try to register with `Ali` it allows me to create user. how can I prevent registering with two same username like `Ali` and `ali` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
def clean_username(self):
    username = self.cleaned_data['username']
    username1=str(username)
    username1=username.lower()
    if User.objects.filter(username=username1).exists():
        self._errors["username"] = ErrorList([u"username exists"])
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is override the UserCreationForm, and write a custom validation to check if that `username__iexact` already exists, and if so, raise a validation error

Comment: I tried this but doesn't work:
`    def clean_username(self, username):
        username = self.cleaned_data['username']
        if User.objects.get(username__iexact=self.cleaned_data['username']):
            raise forms.ValidationError("This username has already existed.")
        return username`